# XML query having arguments from different table

Tags: oracle, xpath

I need to frame a query where the argument to be passed against 'city' here will come form another table by join operation.

Actual query:-

```
SELECT c.cid FROM customer c
     WHERE XMLEXISTS('$d/*:customerinfo/*:addr[ *:city = "Aurora" ]'
       PASSING info AS "d")
```

I want the city value to be come from two different tables by join.
Like:-

```
 SELECT c.cid FROM customer c
     WHERE XMLEXISTS('$d/*:customerinfo/*:addr[ //*:city = $city ]'
       PASSING info AS "d" , (select city from customer C , Office D where C.city = D.city ) as city )
```

This is not working , please suggest an alternate way for it.

Comment: Please always provide example input.

Comment: If `city` is the column you're joining on, then there's little point as you can just take it from `customer` - no join needed. Do you actually want the city for all offices for that customer? That would imply `info` holds data with more than one `city`, of course, so not sure I understand your data model at all...